# Using TypeScript with PhoneGap/Cordova Plugins

Tags: cordova, typescript, phonegap-plugins

I'm running into a bit of a roadblock as I would like to start using the [Google Analytics Cordova plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/GoogleAnalytics) but I'm composing all of my javascript assets in TypeScript. Here is a good example of the specific problem I'm having:

```
window.plugins.googleAnalyticsPlugin.startTrackerWithAccountID("UA-xxxxxxx-x");
```

TypeScript balks at `window.plugins`, throwing the compilation error:

> The property 'plugins' does not exist on value of type 'Window'.

And that makes complete sense. However, I can't get around this by using a `declare var window;` statement, as that creates a duplicate identifier for window.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Step one is to extend the `Window` interface, which you can do like this:

```
interface Window {
    plugins: any;
}
```

This will mean no compiler errors, but unless you extend the definition it means no auto-completion. So this line will now work:

```
window.plugins.googleAnalyticsPlugin.startTrackerWithAccountID("UA-xxxxxxx-x");
```

To take things up a notch and get yourself some auto-completion (and to get your spellings checked too) you can use this extended version of the definition.

```
interface GoogleAnalyticsPlugin {
    startTrackerWithAccountID(accountId: string): void;
}

interface Plugins {
    googleAnalyticsPlugin: GoogleAnalyticsPlugin;
}

interface Window {
    plugins: Plugins;
}
```